# Yii2 модальные окна

Tags: yii2

Есть view куда я хочу вставить модальные окна с готовыми кнопками, заголовками и т.д. , и вызывать их когда нужно .
Вот вью делаю пока для теста

```
<?php
    use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
?>

<?php
Modal::begin([
    'id' =>'modal_win_delete',
    'closeButton' => ['tag' => 'button', 'label' => 'x',],
    'header' => '<h2>Подтвердите действие</h2>',

]);
Modal::end();
?>
```

Вот как я рендерю ее в другом вью

```
<?php
 $this->render('../../modalwindow/modal1.php');
?>
```

ну и собственно кнопка

```
<button type="button" onclick="$('#modal_win_delete').modal('show');" >Открыть</button>
```

при клике окно не всплывает, что я делаю не так?
если этот же код вставляю в первое вью, то окно появляется

Comment: посмотрите в html-код браузера, jquery & bootstrap подключен?

Comment: Да, конечно, в первом же вью все работает

Comment: Ошибки в консоли браузера посмотрите

Comment: Смотрел, нет ошибок. Интересно а никто не делал так, все сразу во вью прописывают модальные окна?

Comment: дело в том, что это выглядит так, что во второе вью не подтянулся js.

Comment: я тоже к этому склонялся, но проверил, все подключено.

Сейчас заметил что кода окна нет, в коде исходном коде страницы, выходит рендер не отрабатывает

Comment: Если бы не было вью, выводилась ошибка, что вью не найден, но ошибки нет Значит по идее что он рендерится?

Comment: В исходном коде нет создаваемого окна, значит рендер не работает

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, а кто echo добавит, Аркадий Израилевич? Не очень хороший подход для создания виджета. Не надо передавать h2 в параметрах, его лучше прописать во вьюшке. В виджет передать только id, title, body. И кнопка вызова модалки почему такая? data-toggle и data-target специально для этого.

Виджет

```
class SimpleModal extends Widget
{
/** @param string $title modal title */
public $title = 'Сообщение';
/** @param string $body modal body */
public $body = '';
/** @param string $options modal attributes */
public $options = [];
/** @var array $params */
public $params = [];

public function run()
{
    $title = $this->title;
    $body = $this->body;
    $options = $this->options;
    $params = $this->params;

    $id = $options['id'] ?? $this->getId();

    return $this->render('simpleModal', compact('id', 'title', 'body', 'options', 'params'));
}

}
```

Вьюшка виджета

```
<div class="modal fade <?=$options['class'] ?? ''?>" id="<?=$id?>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="<?=$id?>">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" title="Закрыть" aria-label="close"></button>
            <p class="modal-title"><?=$title?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><?=$body?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот так вызывать

```
echo \widgets\modal\SimpleModal::widget([
  'title' => 'Title from modal',
  'body' => 'Content from modal',
  'options' => [
      'id' => 'demo_modal',
      'class' => 'modal-normal-width',
  ],
]);
```

Вот и все. Виджет модалки отвечает только за отрисовку модалки, больше он не имеет права ничего делать. Только получить данные и отобразить их в отрисованной модалке. Если нужна другая модалка, добавляем свойство и по умолчанию указываем шаблон `public $template = 'simpleModal';`, при вызове виджета можно указать другой шаблон.

А если уж совсем по феншую, то виджету надо скармливать только один параметр, в который передавать объект, реализующий методы интерфейса `ISimpleModal`

```
public function getId();
public function getTitle();
public function getBody();
public function getOptions();
```

А в виджете уже дергать эти методы и подставлять данные. ТО проще будет управляться. Взять тот же айдишник модалки. Его надо прописать и в модалке и в кнопке, которая вызывает модалку.